# TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments3

Tags: python-2.7

```
class employee:

def _init__(self,name, salary):
    self.name = name
    self.salary = salary
def printemp(self):
    print "Name:" , self.name
    print "Salary:", self.salary

emp1=employee('pavan',29)
emp1.printemp()
```

Whenever I try to execute this, I am getting the below error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "new2.py", line 10, in
>   
>       emp1=employee('pavan',29) TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've missed one `_` before init

Here

```
class employee:
    def __init__(self,name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
    def printemp(self):
        print ("Name:" , self.name)
        print ("Salary:", self.salary)
emp = employee('pavan', 12)
```

Answer (score 1):

The constructor method should be named `__init__`; yours is named `_init__`.